# How to see how many relations a Django model has in admin?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, admin, database-relations

I would like to display how many relations an object has in the Django admin.

Let's say I have the following models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

And I would like to display in the admin (list_display) next to the Poll Question the amount of choices there are. Is there a way to add a function to the class `Question` that will return how many choices it has?

**Edit**

This is a hypothetical model. I am using models with file storage and would like to count how many files are connected to the "main" model, or in this case, the `Question` class.

Comment: Can you try using `count = Question.choice_set.count()` ?

Comment: @anishshah The code I added was a hypothetical model, in my case the `Choice` class is actually a filestorage model and I would like to count how many files are linked to the "Question" model. So choice_set won't work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `list_display` option allows you to specify functions on the `ModelAdmin` itself to display as columns. You don't even need to define that function on your `Question` model, if you're only going to need it for your `ModelAdmin`.

From the [docs of `list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display):

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('upper_case_name',)

    def upper_case_name(self, obj):
        return ("%s %s" % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)).upper()
    upper_case_name.short_description = 'Name'
```

A function specified in your `list_display` attribute will be called with a single parameter: the object that is being displayed. You can obtain the count of its related instances using `RelatedManager.count` on your reverse relation:

```
return obj.choice_set.count()
```

Comment: I understand how this part of `list_display` works. The main question in the OP is however how to count the number of relationships a model has.

Comment: Sorry, I failed to understand the documentation and your answer correctly. I understand now a model has the ability to see the relations with `obj.(modelname in lowercase)_set.count()`. I accepted your answer.